# Software updater just show the menu not the window

Tags: update-manager

I am experiencing problems with software updater in ubuntu 14.04 LTS.
The image below will make it clear. I can not see the window and there is no maximize option when i prees alt+space.What can i do?[The screenshot of the problem . notice this isn't minmized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EkfM6.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would first try to do an update/upgrade in a Terminal.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

I personally do prefer 'synaptic' as application for program installation and update/upgrade [Wikipedia: Synaptic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synaptic_%28software%29)

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

If you are lucky, your problem is solved with an update/upgrade via a Terminal.

If an update/upgrade doesn't help, you could try to reset unity to default settings. One way to do this is...

```
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
unity-tweak-tool --reset-unity
```

Found here... [How do I reset my Unity configuration?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17610/how-do-i-reset-my-unity-configuration)